# Should we allow "please restyle me" or "what could be an appropriate metaphor here" *homework* sort of questions?

Tags: discussion

I think we should, because just that sort of questions made SO very attractive. Rethinking and rewriting someone's text is a good example both for wanderer and teacher.

Comment: Metaphore...? ...

Comment: @JFW Oh, fixed.

Comment: Note this: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/58/should-we-encourage-users-to-give-samples-of-their-writing-for-critique - it'd have to be a lot tighter than "please critique" to be acceptable

Comment: As another note, given the fact that most students have to take literature and writing classes, I'd think we might end up getting homework questions here as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that we should treat this like it has been done on StackOverflow where people are assisted if they have demonstrated some effort on their part. I think it's wrong to become elitist about dishing out assistance. That said, we certainly shouldn't be doing big swathes of work for people like editing their entire book - but if there's a difficulty in a certain section and there is a specific question, I see no reason to deny an answer.

Comment: +1 I actually like this suggestion better than my own.

Answer (score 3):

I've already stated in other questions, but I do believe copy-editing someone else's work should be something we do not do here.  Tips for copy-editing should be fine, but just like with homework questions on SO, we shouldn't do the writer's job for them.

Comment: I don't think that's "just like" SO. On SO it was decided that we should help people without judgement, assuming that they had demonstrated some effort on their part.